# Vue.js and D3.js drag group in SVG failed with an error this.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I have a Vue app that create an SVG then loads data and then for each data add an element into the SVG.

On mounted() I created the d3 as:

**mounted**:

```
this.svg = d3.select("#mobile_pitch")
             .on("touchstart", this.nozoom)
             .on("touchmove", this.nozoom)
             .append("svg");
```

Then a vue.js method load data and adds N groups having a call like:

```
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", this.dragstarted)
    .on("drag", this.draggedGroup)
    .on("end", this.dragended)
  );
```

Everything works well but the drag method "draggedGroup" generates an error on this l code line:

```
d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate('+[d.x,d.y]+')');
```

The error:

> this.setAttribute is not a function...

I should replace "this" with which one?